# How to implement red bar on AVAudioRecorder View as Apple's default audio recorder has?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

i am trying to implement the AVAudioRecorder audio recording with same view as well as effect as Apple's default audio recorder application has. I searched thoroughly but couldn't find the solution. Is there is any way to implement this without breaking Apple's rule.

I though find a way to show the red bar when app is in background and its recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do this as well and my research led me to the conclusion that you can enable the pusling double height red status bar when the app is backgrounded by adding

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

to your *-info.plist file.  However, I do not think there is an easy way to enable this when your app is in the foreground.  In iOS 6 and higher you can change the status bar color, but prior to that it was not possible.  So in iOS 6 you could probably change the color of the bar to red and add a red rect just below the status bar as well to mimic the effect.

Comment: what transition effect i should use to give the same effect as Apple's default AVAudioRecorder gives.Because on recording it gives glow effect on the red bar